# Configure ShadowSocks client on OpenWrt

Tags: proxy, portforwarding, openwrt, socks, tunnel

How do I connect from OpenWrt with ShadowSocks to my server and redirect all traffic through that connection?

I have a ShadowSocks server running on my server. Its working (as tested with my laptop).

Now I want to configure this on my GL-MT300A with OpenWrt. There is the ShadowSocks section in the OpenWrt config, but I don't know what to setup for Transparent Proxy, SOCKS5 Proxy and Port Forward.

[image: OpenWrt ShadowSocks config section]

I did add my ShadowSocks server under "Servers Manage", with the details I would otherwise have in my shadowconfig-client.json file.

All services (Transparent Proxy, SOCKS5 Proxy and Port Forward) are listed above as NOT RUNNING (see image). How do I start those or do I need those for my ShadowSocks client anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted support, and there seems to be an issue with MT300x models. You solve this by running the following from ssh on your router:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libsodium.so.13.1.0 /usr/lib/libsodium.so.18
```